# What is a good way to see logical equivalence statements fast

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I'm preparing for an undergraduate Discrete Mathematics Term test. It seems the exam format includes multiple choice questions(MCQ) and open ended proofs and some of the MCQ surprisingly take up a lot of time. I want to optimise my time for the tougher, rigorous proof questions.

This is an example of a question. Note that $\sim$ means the negation of.

Which of the following are tautologies?

$(I) \sim (p \lor q) \lor [(\sim p) \land q] \lor p$

$(II) [(p \to q) \land (r \to s) \land (p \lor r)] \to (q \lor s) $

$(III) (p \to r) \land (q \to r) \to [(p \lor q) \to r] $

A. None of (I), (II) or (III).

B. (I) and (II) only.

C. (I) and (III) only.

D. (II) and (III) only.

E. All of (I), (II) and (III). (Answer)

I solved it by converting them (on either side of the compound eqn) some form of equations I know of, if not I try to apply some laws/truth table. The second alternative definitely feels super time consuming and may cause me to get careless under time pressure. A good friend of mine said these things come a lot from intuition, but I don't believe I have it. He also used things like

$(p \land r) \to (p \land q)$ is logically equivalent to $(p \land r) \to q$

and $(p \lor q) \to r$ is logically equivalent to $(p \to r) \land (q \to r)$

and $(p \lor q) \to \sim r$ is logically equivalent to $(p \lor r) \to \sim q$

and we can apply $d \land$ on both sides of the compound proposition $(a \lor b) \to c)$  to get $d \land (a \lor b) \to d \land c$

all of which are not obvious to me at first sight until after he gave me an analogy.

Some other questions will be "Which of the following are logical equivalent", haven't found a good question to show here yet.
Does anyone have advice on what to do regarding such problems? Should I keep a library of commonly use proposition logic and their equivalence, negations and what tricks can be applied. If so, where and how can I get them?

Comment: Basically only two ways : either truth table (quite fast with only 2 or 3 prop variables) or reduce them to simpler form by way of rules of equiv.

Comment: Do u mind showing how u would do up a Truth table quickly? For things like (II) I think I would require around 10 columns?

Comment: For the first one, for example, $p \vee \neg p \wedge q$ simplifies to $p \vee q$.  Therefore $I$ is clearly a tautology of the form $A \vee \neg A$.

Comment: For the second, if $p \vee r$ is true, then either $q$ or $s$ must be true because of the two implications inside the square brackets.  Another tautology.

Comment: for (II) $q$ TRUE than $(q \lor s)$ is TRUE than formula is TRUE. Thus, consider the case $q$ FALSE.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi how are you so sure about (II), can you do something a little more rigorous?

Comment: For the third one, you can prove it in various ways, for instance by rewriting $a \leftarrow b$ as $\neg a \vee b$.  With a little practice, though, you'll recognize it as a simple theorem on the spot.

Comment: Yes, I could do it more rigorously, in sundry ways, but I thought you were asking how to solve these problems quickly.  If you want a more elaborate answer, you can say that if either $p$ or $r$ is true, then the antecedent of either $p \rightarrow q$ or $r \rightarrow s$ must be true.  Hence one of the consequents must be true, etc..  Or you can turn everything into a DNF and simplify it, but it takes much longer.  Even writing a truth table takes much longer than the few seconds you need for a problem like this if you practice a bit.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I understand how to do (III) by one of those logic statements I know of, it's exactly the same on RHS and LHS hence logically equivalent, suggesting biconditional and forward direction definitely is true

Comment: Yes, that's how I solved $III$ too.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi could u elaborate why u don't even bother to set the variables of q and s and immediately say "must be true". And what does DNF mean?

Comment: DNF stands for "disjunctive normal form," also known as "sum of products."  If an OR of ANDs of literals.  For an implication like $II$ the idea is that if the antecedent is false, there's nothing to prove.  Hence you look for the consequences of the antecedent being true.  Since the antecedent (the expression in square brackets) is the conjunction of three terms, those three terms must be true for the antecedent to be true.  Starting from the third one is where practice plays a role.  Since the other two are implications, you look for something that will "trigger" either one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83746/discussion-between-prashin-jeevaganth-and-fabio-somenzi).

Comment: Can you use a computer program that you created on the exam?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Sorry for the late reply, missed the notification. I am allowed only a handheld programmable calculator, and even programming in the exam itself would be time consuming, don't know whether it's worth it

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no shortcut.

A systematic way is by filling truth tables, but alas for more than four variables this becomes impractical.

Comment: Do you mind doing up the truth table for (II)?

Comment: I'd rather say that there is no known shortcut that will work in general.  While tautology is coNP-complete, there are many tautologies with short resolution proofs.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi could you get into a room with me for discussion? Though it's a first time using it.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth: yes, I do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

$$(I) \sim (p \lor q) \lor [(\sim p) \land q] \lor p$$

If $p$ is true the third component is true.

If $ p $ is false and $q$ is true the second component is true.

If both $p$ and $q$ are false then the first component is true.

$$(II) [(p \to q) \land (r \to s) \land (p \lor r)] \to (q \lor s)$$

From $(p\lor q) $, one of $p$ or $r$ is true.

Thus from $(p \to q) \land (r \to s)$ we deduct that one of $q$ or $s$ is true, therefore $(q \lor s)$ is true.

$$(III) (p \to r) \land (q \to r) \to [(p \lor q) \to r]$$

If either $p$ or $q$ is true then from $(p \to r) \land (q \to r)$ we deduct that $r$ is true.

Comment: I don't understand the line "Thus from ..." and u have a typo error on the "from $(p \lor q)$ line"

Comment: $p$ implies $q$ and $r$ implies $s$ therefore if one of $p$ or $r$ is true, then one of $q$ or $s$ must be true.

Comment: When you meant one of q or s, do u mean the XOR or do u mean inclusive OR? Also, are q and s meant to be booleans to be set? When doing the full truth table we would have to set it, but this case I observe that you always assume true, why is that so?

Comment: The or is inclusive.  I did not understand  your  second question.

Comment: I only learnt truth tables to be used to test whether 2 statements are logically equivalent. Say prove A \lor B \to C is logically equivalent to D \lor E \to F, then I would need a truth table for 6 columns of A to F at minimum and shown that there isn't any critical row. However, from what I see now you are making a claim of "If one of p or r is true", how are you so sure that q or s must be true? Don't u set these possibilities and assumptions in the truth table as I have mentioned?

Comment: As you  well know the truth table is very time consuming. We can use basic logical equivalences and rules of inference (Modus ponens,Modus tollens, Chain rule,...)     to simplify the logical statements